# What are the steps to ensure a BSA automated review and decision after CustAdd and IdVerifyAdd in jackhenry-jxchange?

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

BSA identify verification, did the CustAdd, IdVerifyAdd, but what needs to happen in order to trigger a true BSA automated review and decision?

We've attempted CustAdd, IdVerifyAdd, and coding the customer as new, as well as any accounts we open in the DMZ, just need to know if we should expect something or if another call is needed to complete the yellowhammer review.